# How to debug Windows Store app when started from secondary tile

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I would like to debug application when started trough secondary tile, as far I can see there is no way to set startup parameters or anything similar, is that possible ?

Comment: Can't you just attach the debugger (Tools/Attach to Process...)?

Comment: it's to late, I want to debug when app is starting

Comment: Store apps have no "startup parameters".  It is very unclear why you would not just open the project in VS and start debugging it or how one app could have two tiles.

Comment: @HansPassant app can have two or more tiles when pin to start option is used, in my case I have news app and there is a option to pin certain category to start menu, secondary tiles : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868249%28v=win.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. In Visual Studio, right-click on your Project > Properties > Debug > Check Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts